# WHERE clause in dynamic TSQL and prevent SQL Injection

Tags: where-clause, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure for selecting rows. I want to pass a parameter to filtering rows dynamically like this :

```
Create Procedure CustomerSelectAll
   @FilterExpresion NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @CMD NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @CMD = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers '+@FilterExpresion;

EXEC(@CMD)
```

The above code works fine, but it is at risk for SQL injection, so I want to be able pass multiple columns with any WHERE statement such as:

```
exec CustomerSelectAll
   @FilterExpresion = N' where Name = 'abc' and family = ''xyz'''
```

Comment: where does the filter expression come from?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware if you can pass the entire where clause as parameter.But from the little amount of knowledge I have, I can suggest you use a [sql parser](http://www.sqlparser.com/) to see if the where clause has just select statements and if the answer is affirmative then you can pass the where clause to your stored procedure. Hope this is of some help.